# CoreAnimation:[EAGLContext renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:] was called from a non-main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

In my Music Application When I am trying to show Ad (I'm using Triton SDK), Sometimes App is crashing and giving me this error:

**CoreAnimation: [EAGLContext renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:] was called from a non-main thread in an implicit transaction! Note that this may be unsafe without an explicit CATransaction or a call to [CATransaction flush].**

My Ads contain both Banner and Audio MP3, Please anyone help me out.

Here is the streaming song code, Which is called continuously:-

```
- (void) configureAudioStremaing {

if ([Singletone sharedSingletone].playMusic == NO) {



    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;

    NSError *activationError = nil;

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&activationError];



    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:&setCategoryError];

    [app beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];



}



else {



    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;

    NSError *activationError = nil;


    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&activationError];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:&setCategoryError];

        [app beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];


}
```

And this following function has been called when Ad is showing All function called in main thread only still I am getting crash issue sometimes:-

```
//for banner view



- (void) showAdbanner {



[Singletone sharedSingletone].impressionUrlCalled = NO;

[[Singletone sharedSingletone].bannerView removeFromSuperview];



BOOL adFrameFound = NO;



for (int i = 0; i < [[Singletone sharedSingletone].ad.companionBanners count]; i++) {



    TDCompanionBanner *banner = [[Singletone sharedSingletone].ad.companionBanners objectAtIndex:i];



    if (banner.width == 300 && banner.height == 250) {

        [Singletone sharedSingletone].bannerView = [[TDBannerView alloc] initWithWidth:banner.width andHeight:banner.height];

        adFrameFound = YES;

        break;

    }

}



if (adFrameFound == NO) {

    [Singletone sharedSingletone].bannerView = [[TDBannerView alloc] initWithWidth:300 andHeight:250];

}



if (songProgressView!=nil) {

    [Singletone sharedSingletone].bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [Singletone sharedSingletone].bannerView.backgroundColor = [blackColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];

    [self.view addSubview:[Singletone sharedSingletone].bannerView];



    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:[Singletone sharedSingletone].bannerView

                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop

                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual

                                                          toItem:songProgressView

                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom

                                                         multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];



    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:[Singletone sharedSingletone].bannerView

                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX

                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual

                                                             toItem:self.view

                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX

                                                         multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

    [[Singletone sharedSingletone].bannerView presentAd:[Singletone sharedSingletone].ad];

    }
```

}

I am getting this report from crashlystics:

http://prntscr.com/kbl58s

Comment: add code please

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

// put your code here to be call
});
```

Comment: I have already used this dispatch_async in the required field can you please tell me in which function I need to use this and I have updated my questions please check once

Comment: also check the code behind this presentAd function call must be there are some transition over there

Comment: Thank you for the response..Yes I have called ShowAdbanner in the main thread, and how can I check transition inside present Ad Sorry but I couldn't understand, Please explain me

Comment: jump to its definition by simple right click on presentAd

Comment: No transition is present inside PresentAd Please check the ss (http://prntscr.com/kbm3sj)

And please check this SS (http://prntscr.com/kbl58s) received from Crashlystics

Comment: as its a framework...you are unable to see inside it

Comment: Yes,  So what will be the solution, please help me

Comment: i cannot but its good if you debug it, create demo app just add banner in it , if still crash exists then it may be bug in framework...